# Does the deletion of files from hdfs removes corresponding hive external table partitions?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a hive external table which creates partitions on a daily basis dynamically.

In order to free up the memory space, I'm planning to delete some of the files from hdfs.

Will the removal of files from hdfs also removes partitions of the corresponding hive table ? (or) Do we need to explicitly remove the partitions of the hive table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the partition separately. I recommend to delete the partition first using hive command and then delete the files.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.